# JMeter - IBM MQ - Sending Unique Data For High Throughput Test

Tags: jmeter

I am having trouble generating unique data for multiple threads and a high throughput test (maximum of 40 requests/second) in a JMeter Test Plan.

I have added the following methods to a test script:

- User parameters which contain variable formats such as: ${__RandomString(6,ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789)}, ${__timeShift(yyMMddHHmm,,P5D,,)} with different variations of the length
- JSR223 PreProcessor using the following format: vars.put("randomtext",UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace('-','').substring(0,30));
- Random Variable with a min value set to "1111111111" and max value set to "9999999999". And "Per Thread(user) = True".

I have used all of these variables types for a single script in different segments within the request body. However, when I run a test with 50 threads (a pool of 100 connections are created at the beginning of the test), ramp-up of 30 seconds and duration of 60 seconds, there are still Duplicate messages reported in the logs of the pods that the message traverse through. Therefore, they do no appear in the queue.

What other method can I try to ensure that each request will be unique and meet the throughput requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Random alphanumeric string of 6 characters gives you 2,176,782,336 unique combinations.

If it's sufficient for your testing you can pre-generate the values using [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) and [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

```
def size = 10000 // or how many unique lines you need

def list = new HashSet<String>()

while (list.size() < size) {
    list.add(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(6))
}

list.each { line ->
    new File('randomStrings.csv') << line.toUpperCase() << System.getProperty('line.separator')
}
```

Then in your main Thread Group use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) and feed this `randomStrings.csv` to it.

Similarly you can handle other parameters.

Comment: Hi Dmitri. Thank you for sharing this. Unfortunately, I am still seeing duplicates being sent as part of the requests. I can see a fit is created in the bin directory. Then after each request I output the variable to a txt file.

D43E1EB18
C53800E5C
D43E1EB18
C53800E5C
D43E1EB18

These are the first few lines of the data file and the threads are using the same values.

Comment: HashSet cannot contain duplicate values by design, make sure to run setUp Thread Group with 1 user and 1 iteration.

Comment: The data set doesn't contain duplicate values. I double-checked that. But the threads are picking up values that have already been submitted by a previous thread. Is there a method of discarding a parameter, once it has been used? The lines of data shared from from different thread numbers.

Comment: If you use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) with [Sharing Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-csv-dataset-config) of "All Threads" it will pick the next line on each iteration of each thread. For Distributed Testing you can consider [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/#HTTP-Simple-Table-Server) with [KEEP=FALSE parameter](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/#READ)